# Rails application not loading javascripts files using assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404

In my rails app, I tried to load CSS into my view like this :

```
<link src="assets/stylesheets/myStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it works.

**BUT**  When I tried to load a JavaScript file as below,

```
<script src="assets/javascripts/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting a `404 error`  (Same error for some images also)

All my files are in the right place, so does anybody have an idea to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to include js and css files into your application.

For current example, put into your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require ./libs/modernizr-2.6.2
```

In your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require ./myStyleSheet
*/
```

And into your .html.erb file (e.g. application.html.erb, in `<head>` section)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, It's help a lot ! 
But one more things : I go an blank page for the js, and so how can i do that for images ?

Comment: For images, put them into app/assets/images, then display on page via <%= image_tag 'my_image.jpg' %>

Answer (score 0):

put a slash '/' before assets in the start of the src. and also css file should be included with link href not with src though it will work but not a good practice.

```
<link href="/assets/css_file_path.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/path_to_js_file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a custom path to the asset pipeline in the below file:

```
 # config/application.rb
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts", "libs")
```

Then, in your JavaScript manifest file (mostly application.js), require the js file in order to take it when doing `pre-compilation`:

```
//= require modernizr-2.6.2.min
```

In your CSS manifest file (mostly application.css.sass), add the below line:

```
/*
 *= require myStyleSheet
*/
```

If you have any individual external JavaScript file to include, you can add them to the precompile array in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['custom.min.js']
```

If you want to see the assets loaded through the asset path, you can use this in the console:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

Hope this could be the best option to use. :)